# How to carry-on a workflow when a parallel task fails

Tags: groovy, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-workflow

I have the following workflow:

```
def flow
node('envinf1')
{
    def buildTasks = [:]
    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        buildTasks[i] = {
            sh 'some command which fails in one of the tasks'
        }
    }
    parallel buildTasks
    echo 'Some message!'
}
```

When one of the tasks fails the workflow never reaches the `echo ...`-line and instead the whole job fails with an exception:

`org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.steps.ParallelStepException: Parallel step 0 failed
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.steps.ParallelStep$ResultHandler$Callback.checkAllDone(ParallelStep.java:153)
...`

Is is possible to tell the `parallel`-step to carry-on with the workflow script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
buildTasks[i] = {
    try {
        sh 'some command which fails in one of the tasks'
    } catch (e) {
        echo "got ${e} but continuing…"
    }
}
```

If you want the build to fail at the end, you can either use the `catchError` step

```
buildTasks[i] = {
    catchError {
        sh 'some command which fails in one of the tasks'
    }
}
```

or write out the equivalent by hand

```
buildTasks[i] = {
    try {
        sh 'some command which fails in one of the tasks'
    } catch (e) {
        echo "failed with ${e}"
        currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
    }
}
```

`catchError` does have one advantage over the hand-built equivalent: it handles `AbortException` (e.g., nonzero exit code from `sh`) by printing a single-line message, `FlowInterruptedException` (e.g., user clicked the stop button) by printing an “aborted by…” message and setting a custom result (like `ABORTED`), and all else by printing a stack trace.